# Update version number with versioneer and GitHub

Tags: github, versioning, git-tag

I am using `versioneer` for several of GitHub-hosted Python projects. It seems that versioneer is installed and works ok, and I can call `project.__version__`.

However, I forgot the procedure on how to update the version number. Should anything in `setup.cfg` or `setup.py` be left untouched?

Is it only the `git tag` command that controls the version number? If I use GitHub's "Draft a new release" would the Python/versioneer version number automatically be updated? Is GitHub's releases the  best way, or should I do, e.g., `git tag v0.2` locally? I suppose that does not matter?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `versioneer` will get the version number from git tag + state of your repository. *NO modifications to your setup files (or **version**.py for the matter) are necessary.* (That's the beauty of versioneer.)

> The document Oleksandr linked to has it all (https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

For example, if you have just tagged your repo as `v1.0`, your code's version (e.g., `import mylib; print(mylib.__version__)`, or `python setup.py version` from the terminal) will show a clean `v1.0`.

If you happen then to modify and/or commit something, the version will update accordingly. In the following, the current state of one of my repos: one commit, plus uncommited changes, on top of a 'v1.1' tag,

```sh
$ python setup.py version

/opt/miniconda3/envs/osh_devel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:506: UserWarning: Normalizing 'v1.1+1.g106ac16.dirty' to '1.1+1.g106ac16.dirty'
  warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
running version
keywords are unexpanded, not using
got version from VCS {'version': 'v1.1+1.g106ac16.dirty', 'full-revisionid': '106ac1638a9a789fa8bdb6df42a608985b18e88c', 'dirty': True, 'error': None, 'date': '2022-03-25T17:01:46+0100'}
Version: v1.1+1.g106ac16.dirty
 full-revisionid: 106ac1638a9a789fa8bdb6df42a608985b18e88c
 dirty: True
 date: 2022-03-25T17:01:46+0100
```

---

**Note about PyPI and `pyproject.toml`**

After adding a `pyproject.toml` file to my library, versioneer stopped working, dropping the error message below whenever I tried to (devel) install:

```sh
$ pip install -e .

Obtaining file:///Users/chbrandt/Coisas/repos/stuff/osh
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/osh_devel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/osh_devel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/osh_devel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/b1/frq3gywj3ljfqrf1yc7zk06r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-6kvnzo67/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 177, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "/private/var/folders/b1/frq3gywj3ljfqrf1yc7zk06r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-6kvnzo67/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 159, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/b1/frq3gywj3ljfqrf1yc7zk06r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-6kvnzo67/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
          import versioneer
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'versioneer'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

> Without `pyproject.toml` everything goes back to normal, working fine.

The issue happens because of an evolutin of python/setup framework as explained in this thread:

- https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer/issues/193#issue-408237852

, right below, in the same thread, you'll see the solution.

Just add `"versioneer-518"` to pyproject's `requires`. E.g.:

`pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "versioneer-518"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer/blob/master/INSTALL.md the steps depend on if your project is distributed with PyPi or through github. But you need to create a new tag when new version needed.