# Failed to install Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I am having issues with installing pandas in docker FROM python:alpine3.7

I get this error

https://github.com/shahadalanazi/Issues/blob/main/Pandas-First

And when I try to install Numpy first for pandas I get this error

https://github.com/shahadalanazi/Issues/blob/main/Numpy-first

I do not want numpy in my docker only pandas but it appears to be a requirement and I do not mind it

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577282/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-versioneer

Comment: `FROM` which image do you start the build of your docker?